# Copy formatted text from excel to word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have an excel sheet with two columns of strings. I track the changes of these two columns using ms-word and copy the result back to a third column. Then I copy the third column to a new word document.

The formating in Excel in Cell C3 is what I would like to transfer to word.
[image: Formating in Excel]

This is what I get at the moment. Notice the complete strike-through.
[image: Formating in Word]

Why does it work twice but not in the third case?

I guess the root of the problem is that I remove the CR/Linefeed in the word to excel step and destroy the boundary of the strike-through-format. My goal is to get each string in one word-paragraph. If I don't remove the CR/Linefeed i get four paragraphs.
Background: In the final application the strings are going to be paragraphs of text.

Sourcecode of the excel-vba-macro (Excel 2010):
Technical remark: You may need to activate the ms-word-objects in excel-vba. (Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library )
The macro assumes, that there a strings in the Range(A1:B3):
for example

```
a string    a string, too
a string    a new string
a string    there is no try
```

The results will be put in the Range(C1:C3).

```
Option Explicit

Dim numberOfBlocks As Long


Sub main()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim tSht As Worksheet
    Dim wordapp As Word.Application
    Dim wdoc As Word.Document

    Set tSht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    numberOfBlocks = 3
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wordapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    For i = 1 To numberOfBlocks
       Call trackChanges(i, wordapp, tSht)
    Next i

    Set wdoc = wordapp.Documents.Add
    Call copyChanges(tSht, wdoc)

End Sub

Sub trackChanges(i As Long, wordapp As Word.Application, tSht As Worksheet)

    Dim diffDoc As Word.Document
    Dim textString() As Variant
    Dim j As Long

    ReDim doc(2)
    ReDim textString(2)

    Set textString(1) = tSht.Range("A" & i)
    Set textString(2) = tSht.Range("B" & i)

    For j = 1 To 2
        With wordapp
                Set doc(j) = .Documents.Add
                textString(j).Copy
                doc(j).Paragraphs(1).Range.PasteSpecial
        End With
    Next j

    wordapp.CompareDocuments OriginalDocument:=doc(1), RevisedDocument:=doc(2), _
        Destination:=wdCompareDestinationNew, Granularity:=wdGranularityCharLevel

    For j = 1 To 2
        doc(j).Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next j

    Set diffDoc = wordapp.ActiveDocument
    wordapp.Visible = True

    'if the answer has two paragraphs, get both in one paragraph
    With diffDoc.Content.Find
                    .Forward = True
                    .Wrap = wdFindStop
                    .Format = False
                    .MatchAllWordForms = False
                   .MatchSoundsLike = False
                    .MatchWildcards = True
                    .Text = vbCrLf
                    .Replacement.Text = " "
                    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
     End With

    diffDoc.Range.Copy
    tSht.Range("C" & i).Select
    tSht.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML"

    With tSht.Range("C" & i)
        .WrapText = True
        .Font.Name = textString(2).Font.Name
        .Font.Bold = textString(2).Font.Bold
        .Font.Size = textString(2).Font.Size
        .Rows.AutoFit
        .Interior.Color = textString(2).Interior.Color
    End With
    diffDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Set diffDoc = Nothing

End Sub


Sub copyChanges(tSht As Worksheet, wdoc As Word.Document)

   tSht.Range("C1:C" & numberOfBlocks).Copy
   wdoc.Range(wdoc.Range.End - 1, wdoc.Range.End).PasteSpecial Placement:=wdInLine, DataType:=wdPasteHTML
   wdoc.Tables(1).ConvertToText Separator:=wdSeparateByParagraphs

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you need to show us an example of exactly what you're getting, and what you expect to get. The result I see when I run your code doesn't match what I understand from your problem description. And I also don't think the result is what you're looking for... I'm also not sure I'm following the logic of what's going on, completely. But from what I'm seeing I suspect you'll need to copy/paste each row entry individually rather than as a block and hope Excel sticks them in the correct cells. I also have to ask myself if it even makes sense to be storing this information in Excel...

Comment: Stepping through a second time gave me a completely different result. All the formatting was retained BUT the information from Row 3 was incomplete. This is due to how Word is comparing two totally different strings: it puts each string in its own paragraph, rather than "merging" two similar strings. The paragraph between them is NOT being removed during Find/Replace (and BTW you should use ^013 as search term not vbCrLf - Word does NOT use that for the paragraph mark, only vbCr) - this might have something to do with Word "protecting" the track changes mark-up.

Comment: If I add code to delete the last paragraph marks in the two documents being compared THEN both sets are on the same line in the comparison document, but without separation. The formatting is retained, however:                 doc(j).Paragraphs.Last.Range.Select : 
                wordapp.Selection.Delete

Comment: I tried your line but it doesnt do the desired trick.

Comment: An improved question would be "how do I remove the paragraph between them while keeping the format.?"